# How to select option in select2 that uses option groups or by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 using option groups like this:

```
<optgroup label="Line Number">
    <option data-order="asc">Orderline</option>
    <option data-order="desc">Orderline</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Order Date">
    <option data-order="asc">Order Date</option>
    <option data-order="desc">Order Date</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ship Date">
    <option data-order="asc">Ship Date</option>
    <option data-order="desc">Ship Date</option>
</optgroup>
```

I want to programmatically select the 2nd option `OrderLine desc`.

The Select2 documentation shows how to select based on val() but I don't know how to apply that here.

```
$('#sortby').val('???').trigger('change.select2');
```

I can't really change the structure of the select2 as it is used in other projects.

I want to trigger the change event because there is a lot of processing that occurs in the handler.

If I could select based on index that would be fine as well.

thx

Comment: Are you wanting to just select based on the data-order="desc" or are you trying to find the value of that option and then if it equals something then trigger something

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the user selecting Ordlerline desc.  Normally I would use the 'trigger' method as I showed in the question but that does not to seem to apply in this case.  End result - the select2 changes to the desired selection and the change event handler fires and processes that selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="sortby">
   <optgroup label="Line Number">
       <option data-order="asc">Orderline</option>
       <option data-order="desc">Orderline</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Order Date">
       <option data-order="asc">Order Date</option>
       <option data-order="desc">Order Date</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Ship Date">
       <option data-order="asc">Ship Date</option>
       <option data-order="desc">Ship Date</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

```
//////////////Select ntn option of select element///////////////

var selectElement=$("#sortby");
function select_ntn_Option(index) {
   $('#sortby option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');
   selectElement.val(null);
   $('#sortby option:eq('+index+')').attr('selected','selected');
   selectElement.trigger('change');
}
select_ntn_Option(5);

//////////////Select ntn option by group title///////////////

var selectElement=$("#sortby");
function select_ntn_Option_ByGroupTitle(groupTitle,index) {
    $('#sortby option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');
    selectElement.val(null);
    $('#sortby>optgroup[label="'+groupTitle+'"]>option:nth-child('+index+')').attr('selected','selected');
    selectElement.trigger('change');
}
select_ntn_Option_ByGroupTitle('Ship Date',2);

//////////////Select last option by text value/////////////////

var selectElement=$("#sortby");
function selectLastOptionByTextValue(value) {
    $('#sortby option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');
    selectElement.val(null);
    $('#sortby option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == value; }).last().attr('selected','selected');
    selectElement.trigger('change');
 }
selectLastOptionByTextValue('Order Date');

//////////////Select last option by group title/////////////////

var selectElement=$("#sortby");
function selectLastOptionByGroupTitle(value) {
    $('#sortby option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');
    selectElement.val(null);
    $('#sortby>optgroup[label="'+value+'"] option').last().attr('selected','selected');
    selectElement.trigger('change');
}
selectLastOptionByGroupTitle('Ship Date');
```

Comment: Okay, I see where you're going with this.  Looks promising.